# Why are my shapes pixelated in Sketch?

Tags: vector, sketch-app, pixel, pixelation

I am only using sketch to design few things and I am new to this.

I was told Sketch is perfect for vector files and it was, until I designed this icon and realized it was pixelated. I am not sure at which point this occurred, but I would like to know how to prevent this issue from happening again.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you accidentally hit `Layer > Flatten Selection to Bitmap` or you've exported a PNG, GIF or JPG which are bitmap formats, and as such are always pixelated. Export as SVG if you need to keep the vector format, or export larger bitmaps, which would be less jaggy.

Answer (score 1):

you have to disable Show Pixels on Zoom
[image: disable Show Pixels on Zoom]

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!